# Legal to post whole music sheet with fingerings?

Tags: discussion

I have seen people post segments of music sheets with title in the screenshot such as "Pirates of the Caribbean."

I'm thinking about posting a whole music sheet of a pop song with all my fingerings annotated, asking for feedback, but I'm not sure if that's legal or acceptable in this community.

Would love to be enlightened, thank you.

Comment: Your fingering is personal to you, and while some may say they're ideal, others will disagree. There will be no consensus that is any more helpful to you than 'this is my fingering, I'm very happy with it, it gets *my* job done'.

Comment: Consult a law site for an answer.  We've had disagreements on this point.  If you are not making money with it and it's for educational purposes you MIGHT be able to w/o legal issues.  I am pretty sure that is fine with small segments of work.

Comment: Also, believe it or not, parody is protected by US copyright.  That is you can do a parody version of someone else's work and not get permission or pay.  But that's not the case you are asking about.

Comment: There is a [related question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/27703/uploading-images-of-music-notation-do-we-violate-copyright-laws) on Law.SE

Comment: I guess you meant: _“legal to post whole **copyrighted** music sheet”_. There are scores which allow re-publishing like those using (some of) Creative Commons licenses or are in public domain.